# Add character to end of field in SQL Database if condition = true?

Tags: sql

I want to add a star `*` to the end of the 'DisplayName' field of any record with a category of 2. Not sure how to do this but I think this is on the right track?

```
UPDATE `table_name`
SET `DisplayName` = replace(DisplayName, 'old_text', 'new_text')
WHERE Category = '2';
```

My problem is I need to just add a space and a character at the end, not do a find and replace.

Comment: Please tag your question with the right RDBMS (vendor and version)! Do you really want to change the DisplayNames persistently? I'd assume, that's an issue for a `VIEW` and should be done dynamically?

Comment: But why do you want to do this? It's generally a bad idea to have "calculated" data stored in the database (data inconsistency...)'. Create a view instead, always returning the correct values.

Comment: Personally, I would add another attribute to the table that is a CHAR(1). Make it nullable, and set the value how you see fit.

Having a value appended to the end, depending on the context, would violate normal form. Again, I would need an example of the data. If, for example, the data is FY (fiscal year) and you are appending 'C' for current, 'P' for past, etc.. then this violates normal form and should be placed into another field.

Comment: It is for digital signage. It displays donors on a php page which displays names on a board. Donors that have passed away have crosses next to their name, etc. DisplayName is what shows on the screen. Regular data ("FirstName", "LastName", "DonationAmount", etc) is also recorded but not shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generic SQL would be:

```
UPDATE `table_name`
    SET `DisplayName` = CONCAT(DisplayName, '*')
WHERE Category = '2';
```

`CONCAT()` can be spelled in different ways depending on the database -- such as `+` or `||`.